# Creating iterables of promise takes longer time

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, promise

I am trying to parallelize my database query using promises.
Suppose I need to make 35000+ database query and I am trying to achieve it using Promise.all([iterables]). The problem I am facing is that, the loop for creating the iterable is taking too long (approximately 25sec) while the await for promises resolve is only taking 15 sec.
I dont understand why the for loop is taking this long since, as per my understanding it is just appending to the promise array and make the promise in pending state.
PS. I am using aws lambda function with memory of 1GB and timeout 1 min.

Here is my sample code:

```
const querymetadata = async() => {
      let result = [],
      lastEvaluatedKey = null;
      const getQuery = {
        TableName,
        KeyConditionExpression: "device_id = :device_id",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":device_id": "EK431",
        }
      };
      do {
        const { Items, LastEvaluatedKey } = await docClient
          .query({ ...getQuery, ExclusiveStartKey: lastEvaluatedKey })
          .promise();
        result = result.concat(Items);
        lastEvaluatedKey = LastEvaluatedKey;
      } while (lastEvaluatedKey);
    console.log(result.length);
    return result.length;
}
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log('start');
    for(let i = 0; i < 35000; i++) {
      promises.push(querymetadata());
    }
    console.log('end');
    await Promise.all(promises);    
    console.log('end lambda');
}
```

In the above code the time taken for start to end console is 25 sec

I have tried the above code in aws lambda function. I dont understand why it is taking this long for the promise iterables to get created

Comment: Could you maybe share `dbQueryFunction`? Perhaps it's doing some synchronous.

Comment: basically, the code in `//...database query` is taking 0.71ms before it returns - on my computer, it's like you're doing `for (let i = 0; i < 2500000; i++);` in there :p

Comment: @NickParsons , it is just dynamodb query. nothing more than that. 
basically like:
const dbQueryFunction = async () => {
   await dynamoDBClient.query({...queryparam}).promise()
}

Comment: @JaromandaX, but here I am using Promise to parallelize right? and why is the array of promise creation takes time as it is just invoking the function and moving it to pending state and later awaiting for it to get fullfilled or rejected right? the await statement should be taking time as it will be waiting it the response, and in my case both the loop and await statement is taking time

Comment: @JudithJoseph Hm, yeah I don't see anything blocking in that code. However, your function should really be `const dbQueryFunction = () => dynamoDBClient.query({...queryparam}).promise();` if that's the only line within it, there is no need to use `await` if there isn't any code following it, and so you can remove the `async` (also, if your arrow function has a body, you should `return` from that body explicitly if you don't want your function returning `undefined`). I doubt that these changes will speed things up much though

Comment: `but here I am using Promise to parallelize right?` synchronous code is still synchronous ... you don't understand Promises, so `basically like` means nothing ... what is the code **exactly** like

Comment: @JaromandaX, the database call is asynchronous right? I have updated the code in the description. Can you please check again? Thanks.

Comment: @NickParsons The code db call is asynchronous right? I have updated the db call in code again now. Can you please check again. Thanks

Comment: sure, but there's 35000 do/while loops, the code has to run sometime, right? async/await doesn't give you new "threads" or anything

Comment: Okay I understand @JaromandaX. Can you suggest me a better way to do n number of asynchronous calls if u have done similar please ? N can be 1000s or even millions.

Comment: To be honest, I can't really say where the "bottleneck" is - I'd be checking if there's some concurrency limit on queries to the database that you could increase? Out of interest, what database are you using?

Comment: @JaromandaX I am using aws dynamo db. And there is no really query limit as far as it reaches a limit. Because it is auto scalling

Answer (score 0):

With your code, all the promises are queued at the same time then, they start when you call the "await".
It should be better to create some kind of queue.

Here is a really basic example, it executed 3 operations in parallel and wait for the final results including everything :

```js
function op(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(`ok ${id}`)
        }, 1000)
    })
}

const MAX_CONCURRENT = 3
let pendingCount = 0
const results = []

function runNextOp(finalResolve) {
    if ((pendingCount < MAX_CONCURRENT) && (actionsParam.length > 0)) {
        const p = actionsParam.shift()

        op(p).then((res) => {
            results.push([p, res])
            pendingCount -= 1
            runNextOp(finalResolve)

            if ((pendingCount === 0) && (actionsParam.length === 0)) {
                finalResolve(results)
            }
        })

        pendingCount += 1
    }
}

const actionsParam = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

function allOps() {
    return new Promise((finalResolve) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < MAX_CONCURRENT; i += 1) {
            runNextOp(finalResolve)
        }
    })
}

(async () => {
    const allResult = await allOps()
    console.log(allResult)
})()
```